# Service not Starting when i destroy and start via Receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

When i start service via `Broadcast Receiver` its showing me the logcat

```
01-29 12:20:33.245: W/ContextImpl(4721): Implicit intents with startService are not safe: Intent { act=actions.com.sound_profile_change.MyService } android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:494 android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:494 actions.com.sound_profile_change.MyReceiver.onReceive:30 
01-29 12:20:33.245: W/ActivityManager(511): Unable to start service Intent { act=actions.com.sound_profile_change.MyService } U=0: not found
```

In Service Side:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    timer.cancel();
    timerTask.cancel();

    Intent intent = new Intent("This.is.Receiver");
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

In Receiver Side:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     if(context!=null){
          System.out.println("Am in Receiver ");
          System.out.println("Not Null :>>"+context);
          Intent services = new Intent();
          services.setAction(
                "actions.com.sound_profile_change.MyService");
          context.startService(services);
          // context.startService(new Intent(context, MyService.class));

     }else{
           System.out.println("Its Null");
     }
}

In Manifest File:

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">


    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name=".MyService"
        android:enabled="true" />

    <receiver android:name=".MyReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="This.is.Receiver"/>

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

</application>
```

Help Me...

Comment: It would help if you could show some code of the service and how you start it

Comment: In future, consider indenting code with four spaces to apply formatting.  Makes it much easier to read!

Comment: post a code where you are starting a service.

Comment: give me some Ideas . I already tried some code which i grab from stackoverflow. its Helpless

Comment: Have you registered a BroadcastReciever at all?

Comment: Is your service/broadcast receiver added into AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: yes I updated my code . kindly check it

Answer (score 0):

"Implicit intent" warning that your are getting is because Using Implicit Intents you have not mentioned a specific component (for example: name of service class).

Implicit Intents does have not specified a component; instead, they must include enough information for the system to determine which of the available components is best to run for that intent.

So, it means the component will now be chosen by Android intent-filter mechanism, by given Intent-Action.

You may try following in code while starting a service:

```
        Intent services = new Intent(context,MyService.class);//Explicit mention of service class name while creating intent        
        services.setAction("actions.com.sound_profile_change.MyService");
        context.startService(services);
```

Above code is now using "explicit intent". Explicit Intents have specified a component which provides the exact class to be run.

Comment: I tries this code. And i set the action for the intent

Comment: @Sugumaran I modified a code after your edit, and edited my post. Try with latest code that I posted. It should work!!

Comment: @Sugumaran have you implemented onStartCommand in service? because when we start service using context.startService(services); it will invoke onStartCommand () in a service

Comment: @Sugumaran: did you tried implementing onStartCommand() in a service with above solution?